# Orientdb csv import lost data

Tags: csv, etl, orientdb

I am trying to load some csv data into Orientdb.

OrientDb is installed on Windows at `c:/oreientdb/orientdb-community-2.1.15`.  I am using the etl file below:

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "f:/MOH/datamodel/audititem.txt" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {}},
  "transformers": [
    { "vertex": { "class": "AuditIssue" } }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal:/orientdb/orientdb-community-2.1.15/databases/'MOH v1.0'",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [
         {"name": "AuditIssue", "extends": "V"},
       ], "indexes": []
   }
  }
}
```

When I run this through the oetl utility, I get no errors

```
OrientDB etl v.2.1.15 (build 2.1.x@r243c566d47d8877ea0075b8f61abc8880f810a42; 2016-04-04 12:07:47+0000) www.orientdb.com
BEGIN ETL PROCESSOR
[file] INFO Reading from file f:/MOH/datamodel/audititem.txt with encoding UTF-8
+ extracted 71 rows (0 rows/sec) - 71 rows -> loaded 71 vertices (0 vertices/sec) Total time: 1010ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
+ extracted 205 rows (132 rows/sec) - 205 rows -> loaded 204 vertices (131 vertices/sec) Total time: 2025ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
END ETL PROCESSOR
+ extracted 495 rows (350 rows/sec) - 495 rows -> loaded 495 vertices (351 vertices/sec) Total time: 2853ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
```

But the class does **not** appear in the database.

How should I setup the etl process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two errors here.

1. The single quote `'` aroung the dbUrl was unnecessary.
2. The server needed to be stopped while the etl was taking place.

The json file now is as follows:

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "f:/MOH/datamodel/audititem.txt" } },
  "extractor": { "csv": {}},
  "transformers": [
    { "vertex": { "class": "AuditIssue" } }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal:/orientdb/orientdb-community-2.1.15/databases/MOH v1.0",
       "dbUser": "admin",
       "dbPassword": "admin",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "classes": [
         {"name": "AuditIssue", "extends": "V"},
       ], "indexes": []
   }
  }
}
```